# How to use network analysis (shortest path, point to point) on multiple points [QGIS 3.16.8-Hannover]

Tags: network, network-analysis

I have a project with 4 layers, two point layers with multiple destination points, another layer with a few starting points and a layer 'roads' that have routes from the starting points to each destination points and a final polygon layer.
Each polygon layer contains a starting point and a few destination points.

I would like to calculate the optimum distance from each starting point to each destination point.
For that I have been using network analysis (shortest path, point to point) in batch, it works well.

Would it be possible to automatize this process by first selecting each starting poing and destination point that is inside each polygon and then calculating the optimum routes?

For example:

Polygon A - Has 10 destination points, using this process I get 10 optimum routes for this polygon.

Polygon B - Has 20 destination points, using this process I get 20 optimum routes for this polygon.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it in the original post, it's 3.16.8-Hannover

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.